# use tailwind ring but change the box shadow radius?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to use the ring-2 from tailwind but I have no idea how to change the shadow blur property only, without changing the tailwind internal custom properties in the css or adding a custom shadow to the config file.

here is the example:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/cqOst4w660

Any clues?

Comment: how you tried using `shadow-md` `shadow-lg`

Comment: Because the effect is already there with ring. Just missing the blur. The shadow does not give the outer shape which then falls into the same issue. I need to either define the full shadow or set in the config file.

Comment: I think you can't change the box-shadow blur without setting the other values, because there's no single css prop for that. What's the problem with your current solution of a custom class? Seems fine for me, if you don't plan to use variants of that on multiple components.

Comment: there is no issue putting it on css or just doing it the way it is. But I loose intelisense and using another prop that changes the internal custom properties would cause issues. But again not a big deal, I was just curious how to solve this and I posted a answer how I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended adding a new utility, since it looks I need to set the tailwind custom properties individually, which are 3 and it would not work by extending theme.

This solved all the issue I can think of, you will still get the intellisense and the warn if you use another ring variant like ring/ring-1/ring-2/etc.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/KM2lDNpbtX